# MSTest: TestInitialize method doesn't seem to be executed

Tags: mstest

This "question" is a documentation of an odd MSTest behaviour I've banged my head against a few times, in the hope that it will be useful to other people that encounter the same problem. Consider the following test:

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeTest {
    private List<int> _list;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp() {
        DoSomething();
        _list = new List<int>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTestMethod() {
        _list.Add(42);
        ...
    }
}
```

Running it produces a `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the `_list.Add(42);` line. It looks like `SetUp()`, although it has the correct `public void` signature and the `[TestInitialize]` attribute, isn't invoked. What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, further investigation showed that `DoSomething()` was throwing an exception. For reasons I cannot comprehend, MSTest (at least when invoked from Visual Studio with ReSharper) *swallows exceptions thrown by the `[TestInitialize]` method and continues with the test method anyway without failing the test*.

(If anyone can explain the rationale for this behaviour or how it can be turned off, I'd be grateful.)